# Cannot replicate AJAX POST into Postman

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, postman

This is my AJAX POST request to the page `save.php` that works properly.

```
function updateJson(jsonarr){
        var convertedJson = JSON.stringify(jsonarr);

        $.post('save.php', {data: convertedJson}, function(result){});
    }
```

**convertedJson** is `[{"name":"Test1","score":"1"},{"name":"Test2","score":"0"}]`

[image: AJAX Post request infos]

When i try POSTing to the same page by using Postman (or other REST Clients) with the same body, i get Code 200 but the request does not go through.

[image: Postman]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending as form-encoded content in postman? Not much detil here to work with

Comment: Sorry. I added a screenshot of the Postman request.

Comment: OK you need to send as form encoded and have that json string as value for the key named `data`

Comment: If you wrote or can edit the save.php endpoint, perhaps you want to add debug code there so that you can see what the request looks like in the two different cases

Comment: @charlietfl That worked. Had to use x-www-form-urlencoded. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use x-www-form-urlencoded as Body type, with "data" as Key and the Json as Value.